# Как остановить выполнение кода JS?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени! У меня есть такой код

```
            success: function(data) {
                    $(".omenaforpost").html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var row = data[i];
                    if(row.rid == 1 || row.rid == 2)
                        $(".omenaforpost").append("<div style='background:#8cb18c;' class='omenapostcab' id='"+row.id+"'><span class='omenaprochitano'> Удалить</span><span uid='"+row.uid+"' class='omenaotvet'>Ответить |</span><p>"+row.msg+"</p></div>");
                    else
                        $(".omenaforpost").append("<div class='omenapostcab' id='"+row.id+"'><span class='omenaprochitano'> Удалить</span><span uid='"+row.uid+"' class='omenaotvet'>Ответить |</span><p>"+row.msg+"</p></div>");
                    var classpost = $('.omenaprochitano');
                    var omenaotvet = $('.omenaotvet');
                }
```

он выдает вот такую ошибку если туда приходит пустой массив как я понял

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

подскажите как исправить данную ситуацию! то есть он работает! но если в базе пусто выходит ошибка в консоль! как предотвратить?

Comment: а при чем тут заголовок ? вы не можете новый придумать ?

Comment: ошибка в том что data===null наверное ваш  (видимо ajax) запрос возвращает не то, что ожидаете.

Comment: не понял! это кроссбраузерный аякс запрос! консоль от браузера возвращает такую ошибку

Comment: я сказал что data is null и это так. почему это произошло я не знаю и знать не могу, выведите console.log(data) перед циклом.

Comment: если вы про заголовок вопроса то как остановить выполнение кода если массив пустой! или как лучше решить данную задачу?

Comment: Странно, что никто так и не ответил человеку, как остановить выполнение кода. @Сашка, вставьте ключевое слово debugger в нужном месте (например сразу после открывающей фигурной скобки), при выполнении кода js-дебаггер остановится в этом месте и можно будет спокойно отлаживать код. И еще, почитайте о принципе DRY, будет полезно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-первых, конструкция с data.length ужасна. Можно же проще: for(i in data). Уже легче станет, ошибка уйдёт

Comment: чет настолько много рекомендаций не делать итерацию `for (var i in array)` что мб. действительно не стоит предлагать (правда все они упираются в то что прототип Array может быть изменен)

Comment: в данном случае какой прототип Array? :) В лучшем случае следующий вопрос будет «что такое прототип?».

Comment: Cделал по вашему)

Comment: ну я про то, что это bad practice в глазах 60% js кодеров, да и действительно, потом они начинают итерацию таким образом  через nodeList, думая что это массив итд итп. так что лучше in использовать только к конкретным объектам.

Comment: вы меня просветили, спасибо :) В самом деле, пора бы уже озаботиться изучением js, в веб-разработке без него практически никуда. А js хоть и местами похож на питон, но своеобразен.

Comment: И к конкретным объектам с `for (var p in o)` фигня получается. Можно какой-нибудь Ember использовать, который прототип объекта расширяет и всё к чертям.

Но волков бояться - в лес не ходить.

Comment: Фууу, какой вредный совет. НИКОГДА не стоит итерироваться по массиву с помощью for ... in.

Comment: @dzhioev кроме того что Array может быть изменен есть какие-нибудь причины ? Я например считаю, что библиотека расширяющая встроенные прототипы должна быть выпилена.

Comment: Во-первых, никогда нельзя гарантировать, что какая-нибудь другая библиотека не добавит что-нибудь в прототип. Во-вторых, порядок обхода c помощью for ... in произвольный. В-третьих, даже если порядок правильный, for ... in пропускает пустые элементы массива, что не всегда допустимо.

Comment: 1. можно гарантировать, просто не пользоваться такими библиотеками.
 2. порядок не сильно нужен
 3. опять-же иногда пропуск нужен, скажем у вас такой код: 


    var a=[];
    a[100000]=1;

 перебор по length в данном случае overkill. правда, можно воспользоваться `.map()`

Comment: Просто `for( el in arr)` работает не совсем явно с массивами. Создан он для объектов, а значит и массивы видит как объекты, отсюда вытекает, что текущий индекс будет строкой, а не числом, как если бы мы использовали `for(var i = 0... )`, что то же может вызвать некоторые проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как насчет "ужасная", но по скорости, конструкция с ***in*** очень затратная, раза в 4ре

**Проверяем**:

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<300000;i++){
    arr[i]="Значение "+i;
}
```

**Test speed 1**:

```
console.time('test speed 1');
for(i in arr){
    arr[i]+=" GO!";
}
console.timeEnd('test speed 1');
```

***Итог:***
*test speed 1: 252.000ms*

**Test speed 2**:

```
console.time('test speed 2');
for(var i=0,x=arr.length;i<x;i++){
    arr[i]+=" GO!";
}
console.timeEnd('test speed 2');
```

***Итог:***
test speed 2: 68.000ms

Comment: вот наконец полезная инфа про `for in` а-то у меня вменяемых аргументов как-то не было. thx.

Comment: Вообще красава)

Answer (score 0):

там не массив пустой, там null

```
if(!data) return;
```

Comment: Спасибо РАБОТАЕТ!) я так делал только вместо return continue писал))

Answer (score 0):

> Не знаю как насчет "ужасная", но по скорости, конструкция с in очень затратная, раза в 4ре

Угу. И часто вы обрабатываете массивы размером 300000? 
Давайте проверим на 3000?

test speed 1: 1.000ms

test speed 2: 0.000ms

Неожиданно, правда?
А код внутри итераций одинаково выполняется по скорости.